# Transfer files between a HPC computer to my local computer having another server between

Tags: ssh, scp

I am working on an ssh Linux server that is on other servers. To log in I have to log first into the first server and then from this go to the server I work.

I do this with an alias

```
ssh -J first@ssh.university.ac.uk second@whatever.foo.ac.uk
```

If I want to transfer files using `scp` from second@whatever.foo.ac.uk to my local computer I have first move the file to first@ssh.university.ac.uk and then from this to my computer. Is there a way to do this directly???

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Why do you want to do this? This is what you are describing. https://www.varonis.com/blog/what-is-a-proxy-server

Comment: Hi, Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64. I want to do this to transfer files from the server to my computer to do things I cannot do on the server.

Comment: That is not a version of Ubuntu that is a kernel version of something I do not know of what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scp` command understands the `-J` option, too. So analogously to your `ssh` command, you can do

```
scp -J first@ssh.university.ac.uk second@whatever.foo.ac.uk:junk.file local/garbage
```

Comment: Great! I will try tomorrow. If working, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using aliases, I'd suggest creating a ~/.ssh/config file entry in which you can set a `ProxyJump` or `ProxyCommand` for Host whatever.foo.ac.uk - that way it should work for both ssh and scp. Something like:

```
Host hpc
  Hostname    whatever.foo.ac.uk
  User        first
  ProxyJump   second@ssh.university.ac.uk
```

You should then be able to just do

```
ssh hcp
```

or

```
scp hcp:/path_to_remote/file localfile
```

and so on transparently, regardless of your local shell. See for example

- [How To Use SSH ProxyJump and SSH ProxyCommand](https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-proxyjump-ssh-proxycommand/)